# "track by $index" creating duplicates on save using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having a problem when I update my object, it's creating a duplicate of this instance (singleOrder) in the model, instead of updating the exisiting one. I can't clear the whole $scope and reload, as I'm only updating part of the object.

Here's my save function:

```
$scope.saveDetails = function(singleOrder, data, status) {              

    OrdersService.updateOrders(singleOrder.order)

    .success(function(data, status) {
        angular.extend(singleOrder, data);                      
    })                             
}
```

Where **singleOrder** relates to an instance of my main **OrderDetails** object, used in **ng-repeat**

```
<div ng-repeat="singleOrder in orderDetails track by $index">
```

**Here's the function called in my OrdersService, if that helps:**

```
getData.updateOrders = function(data){
    var url = '/service/rest/orders';

    return $http.post(url, data)                    
};
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

**UPDATE:
I've tried messing around with the `track by` and received the following results:**

`<div ng-repeat="singleOrder in orderDetails track by $index">`
Saves the content fine, but creates a duplicate order on dom.

`<div ng-repeat="singleOrder in orderDetails track by singleOrder.order.id">`
This works as each order has a unique id. I can save fine and it doesn't create a duplicate in the dom, but I get a **Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed** in the console.

Confused as to why this is happening. Any ideas welcome!

Comment: check the runtime values  of `data` and `singleOrder` at the `extend` step

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DivyaMV. I've checked both `data` & `singleOrder` and they are both updated with the new values. Could you be more specific on what I need to verify? Thanks again.

Comment: at the debug point verify if both the objects are holding the values that they are supposed to.

Comment: Hi @DivyaMV yes they are both holding the correct, updated values. The main `orderDetails` is showing the object twice, which is the problem, whereas `data` and `singleOrder` are showing the value once. So somehow it is being injected into `orderDetails` twice.

Answer (score 2):

angular.extend() returns the destination object, so maybe you could do something like this

```
OrdersService.updateOrders(singleOrder.order)
.success(function(data, status) {
    singleOrder = angular.extend(singleOrder, data);                      
})
```

But in my opinion it is better when server returns the whole object that the client needs. The code will be easier.

Comment: How is `singleOrder = angular.extend(singleOrder, data);`  different from `angular.extend(singleOrder, data);`

Comment: Well.. it is not really different, the object singleOrder is the same in both cases. I just do not undestand how @Desmond can have duplicated items created by this code ... I think that because there is `track by $index` instead of `track by SomeIdProperty`, that angular really treats both singleOrders as different objects.  If that is so, then `track by SomeIdProperty` would result in an exception

Comment: `server returns the whole object that the client needs` What about a scenario when you'd like that object to have some functionality?

Comment: Thanks for your replies @DavidVotrubec @Dviya MV and @Kirill Slatin. I tried changing it to `track by order.id` (each has a unique ID), but I get the error "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed". Whether I have `track by $index` or nothing, it still creates duplicates. Any other ideas? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on this, it appears the issue wasn't with Angular, it was the data in the object. I can't say exactly what part was the problem, but after the content was updated, this started working with `track by $index`.

Thanks everyone for trying to help!